# Use ActionBar Tabs to Switch Views

Tags: android

Is there a way to use ActionBar tabs, but with the tabs switching ContentViews instead of fragments? The issue is that I have dual-pane layouts on large screens that have a fragment in each of two panes and I'd want to switch out the whole container view when that tab is selected.

Currently I'm using my own tabbing mechanism, but I'd like to integrate better into the built-in features and behavior of the ActionBar, and to save space by not having to have a separate ActionBar and tab bar when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Action Bar docs --

> To get started, your layout must include a ViewGroup in which you
>   place each Fragment associated with a tab. Be sure the ViewGroup has a
>   resource ID so you can reference it from your tab-swapping code.
>   Alternatively, if the tab content will fill the activity layout
>   (excluding the action bar), then your activity doesn't need a layout
>   at all (you don't even need to call setContentView()). Instead, you
>   can place each fragment in the default root ViewGroup, which you can
>   refer to with the android.R.id.content ID (you can see this ID used in
>   the sample code below, during fragment transactions).

If you specify a layout for your activity with slots for two fragments, you can replace them both (or even just one if that makes sense your app) in the `ActionBar.TabListener` callback.  The callback still leaves you in control of the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My situation is a bit more complex since two of my tabs would have single full-screen fragments while the other two have the dual-pane, two-fragment layout. So I do have to switch layouts somehow. Maybe some tricks with hiding and showing views within the larger ViewGroup?

Comment: You can modify your layout in the callback, so the standard `setVisiblity` tricks to hide half the layout with `GONE` should work to swap layouts should work fine.

Comment: Because of the way my app was originally written (when Android 2.1 was current), this is going to be a lot more work than I hoped. On the other hand, it will make my app conform to standards better (i.e., make it a true fragment-based app) and I can toss out some of the existing kludges that have often led to obscure bugs. Thanks for the help!